# Find functions in ps1 and invoke

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How can I find all functions present in a specific .ps1 file that have been dot sourced and invoke those methods in a loop? (No parameters are required)

We know that using Get-ChildItem function:\ will list all methods in the shell.

One solution could be to use a specific naming convention for all functions in .ps1 file and use Get-ChildItem function:\unique_pattern* search. This does feel a bit fragile.

Also, I have no idea how I would invoke the function based on the return info from Get-ChildItem. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Listing all top-level function names in a ps1 file using PowerShell 3.0+ [Language namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.language.aspx) parser::

```
$code = Get-Content -literal 'R:\source.ps1' -raw
$fns = [Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($code, [ref]$null, [ref]$null).
    EndBlock.Statements.
    FindAll([Func[Management.Automation.Language.Ast,bool]]{
        $args[0] -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst]
    }, $false) |
    Select -expand Name
```

Invoking a function by name in a variable after dot-sourcing the script:

```
& $name param1 param2 param3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (not convinced it is the best one, however, but might give you another track to follow, depending on your use case):

```
$before = dir function:\

. .\test.ps1
# test.ps1 contains
# function f1 { Write-Output "f1 called" }
# function f2 { Write-Output "f2 called" }
# function f3 { Write-Output "f3 called" }

$after = dir function:\

$newFunctions = compare-object $before $after | ?{ $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | select -ExpandProperty InputObject

$newFunctions | %{
    . $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function created by *Ronald Rink*.
You can save the script as .ps1 and after you execute it , you will be able to see the functions inside it. SO, you can put it in your script also to enumerate all the custom functions.

He has used the [Abstract Syntax Tree class(AST)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.ast)  to achieve it.

Here is the reference link for the same: [Enumerate all PS Functions in a Script File](https://d-fens.ch/2015/04/26/nobrainer-enumerate-all-functions-in-a-powershell-script-file-via-ast/)

```
[CmdletBinding(
    SupportsShouldProcess = $true
    ,
    ConfirmImpact = 'Low'
    ,
    DefaultParameterSetName = 'list'
)]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'list')]
    [Switch]
    $ListAvailable = $true
)

BEGIN
{
    function functionInBeginBlock()
    {
        return "functionInBeginBlock";
    }

    function getFunctions($_MyInvocation)
    {
        $OutputParameter = @();
        foreach($BlockName in @("BeginBlock", "ProcessBlock", "EndBlock"))
        {
            $CurrentBlock = $_MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Ast.$BlockName;
            foreach($Statement in $CurrentBlock.Statements)
            {
                $Extent = $Statement.Extent.ToString();
                if([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Statement.Name) -Or $Extent -inotmatch ('function\W+(?<name>{0})' -f $Statement.Name))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $OutputParameter += $Statement.Name;
            }
        }
        return $OutputParameter;
    }
}

PROCESS
{
    function functionInProcessBlock()
    {
        return "functionInProcessBlock";
    }
}

END
{
    function functionInEndBlock()
    {
        return "functionInEndBlock";
    }

    function theAnswer()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    return getFunctions($MyInvocation);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ronald and @wOxxOm's answer, this is a single line method to provide the currently executing script file's locally defined functions. Any `dot` sourced functions will not show up here since we are using AST. Another thing to notice is this will handle the cases where you do not have any `Begin` or `Process` blocks, since AST will put entire script into `End` block in that case.

`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Ast.EndBlock.Statements.Where({$_ -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst]}) | Select -expand Name`